# Is there a plural form of teeth?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is teeth's a word? Would you say my teeth's enamel is coming off, or my tooth enamel is coming off?

Comment: _Teeth_ **is** the plural form. Are you looking for something else, the possessive form perhaps?

Comment: "Teeth" is plural. "Teeth's" is possessive. "Tooth enamel" sounds more natural, but one could equally say "teeth's enamel" (plural) or "tooth's enamel" (singular).

Comment: This question may be asked on [ell.se]

Answer (score 6):

*Teeth* is the plural. *Tooth* is the singular.

*Teeth's* is the possessive plural and *Tooth's* the singular possessive. This is one way to form the genitive, the other being through *of* ("my tooth's enamel", "the enamel of my tooth").

Comment: Or, as the OP was trying to say, "the enamel of my *teeth*".

Answer (score 1):

Either way it would be awkward. You have correctly noted that the plural of *tooth* is *teeth*. As such it should have been

> *My teeth' s enamel …

However, we do not say *tooth's enamel* or *teeth's enamel*. Instead, we say

> The enamel on my teeth …